# How to draw a QR code with Qt in native C/C++

Tags: c++, qt, render, qr-code

**QR in Qt**

As a companion question to [How to scan for QR codes with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603664/how-to-scan-for-qr-codes-with-qt-in-native-c-c), I want to know how to draw a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) from native C/C++ code in my Qt5 based desktop app, but I could not find an example of how to do this.

I know [QtQR](http://code.google.com/p/qtqr/) exists, but it has dependencies on [python-qrtools](https://code.launchpad.net/~qr-tools-developers/qr-tools/trunk) which in my opinion kind of defeats the purpose of using Qt in the first place. I want a nimble, efficient and dependency-free solution that will compile with my app wherever I decided to take it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you feel that Fukuchi's library is too large<sup>[0]</sup> for you, consider looking at Nayuki's C++ QR Code generator library<sup>[1]</sup>: https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator/tree/master/cpp

Nayuki's library requires C++11, and is portable without needing Autotools. Sample usage:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "QrCode.hpp"
using namespace qrcodegen;

// Create the QR Code object
QrCode qr = QrCode::encodeText("Hello, world!", QrCode::Ecc::MEDIUM);

// Read the black & white pixels
for (int y = 0; y < qr.size; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < qr.size; x++) {
        int color = qr.getModule(x, y);  // 0 for white, 1 for black

        // You need to modify this part
        draw_pixel_onto_QT(x, y, color);
    }
}
```

<sup>[0]: Fukuchi: 20 files, ~7200 lines among the main .c and .h files (excluding build and test code).</sup>
<sup>[1]: Nayuki: 6 files, ~1400 lines among the main .cpp and .hpp files (excluding demo code).</sup>

---

**EDIT 2016-12-08 by OP**
I decided, with permission, to add my own adaption to Qt. This code compiles and runs fine on my system, And I think it should be independent enough to work elsewhere without too many tweaks as well.

```
#include "QrCode.hpp"

void paintQR(QPainter &painter, const QSize sz, const QString &data, QColor fg)
{
    // NOTE: At this point you will use the API to get the encoding and format you want, instead of my hardcoded stuff:
    qrcodegen::QrCode qr = qrcodegen::QrCode::encodeText(data.toUtf8().constData(), qrcodegen::QrCode::Ecc::LOW);
    const int s=qr.getSize()>0?qr.getSize():1;
    const double w=sz.width();
    const double h=sz.height();
    const double aspect=w/h;
    const double size=((aspect>1.0)?h:w);
    const double scale=size/(s+2);
    // NOTE: For performance reasons my implementation only draws the foreground parts in supplied color.
    // It expects background to be prepared already (in white or whatever is preferred).
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(fg);
    for(int y=0; y<s; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<s; x++) {
            const int color=qr.getModule(x, y);  // 0 for white, 1 for black
            if(0!=color) {
                const double rx1=(x+1)*scale, ry1=(y+1)*scale;
                QRectF r(rx1, ry1, scale, scale);
                painter.drawRects(&r,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For usage, please see this [painter](https://github.com/mrdeveloperdude/OctoMY/blob/master/src/libs/libqr/qr/QRPainter.cpp) class.

Comment: Hi! I integrated your QR Code into my project, and if you want I can edit your answer with the Qt specific code I made, that way it will be a better fit for my question?

Comment: If you have the actual Qt code that can compile and run, I would be very happy to receive the edit!

Comment: I tried using your library, and i get the QrCode  drawing, but when i scan it, its not recognized, the scanner doesn't get anything...

Comment: @Xsmael Please post your input text and a picture of the QR Code you generated. You may comment on this thread, email me privately, or start a new Stack Overflow question. I will test and debug your case.

Comment: @Nayuki, thank you for your help!, i made a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979325/drawing-qr-code-with-qt-in-native-c-c-using

Comment: @LennartRolland: `char *str=data.toUtf8().data();` - I don't think this is safe. The QByteArray returned by toUtf8() is destroyed at the end of the full-expression, so the char* representation of it becomes a dangling pointer.

Comment: @LennartRolland: When can `qr.getSize()` be <= 0?

Comment: @StefanMonov: Thanks for uncovering that, and sorry for nt replying sooner, I first saw your comment now. I will update it to be safer!

Comment: I am evaluating @Nayuki's QR library. The JavaScript demo on their site looks attractive, however, I am unable to find 'Scale: pixels per module' option in C version. Is it supported? and if so how. Thanks.

Comment: @FractalSpace You will need to do the pixel scaling by yourself in C. You can take ideas from my relevant [Java function](https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator/blob/8518684c0f33d004fa93971be2c6a8eca3167d1e/java/src/main/java/io/nayuki/qrcodegen/QrCode.java#L288-L313) and [JavaScript function](https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator/blob/8518684c0f33d004fa93971be2c6a8eca3167d1e/typescript-javascript/qrcodegen.ts#L244-L261).

Comment: Thanks @Nayuki. I will take a look.

Answer (score 31):

**UPDATE 3/3-2016:** It has come to my attention that there is a small library project that does what my answer does but in a more "prepackaged" way. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/yoneal/qtqrencode/tree/master/qqrencode).

**QR in Qt**

There is a small QR-code generator library in pure C and without dependencies, called [libqrencode](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/).

**Step 1: Install**

Before you can use it, you will have to install it. On my Ubuntu 13.10 that meant typing the following in a shell:

```
sudo aptitude install libqrencode-dev
```

On other platforms you may have to build it from source by yourself. Simply download the tarball and follow the instructions from the [source code download](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/).

**Step 2: Project file**

Next, you will have to add the library to your project. In my Qt5.2.0 project file (myproject.pro or similar) that meant appending the following line:

```
LIBS += -lqrencode
```

This should be similar for most versions of Qt that I know.

**Step 3: encode**

Next one must write the code that actually uses the library to encode some input string to QR format. That is one line of code:

```
QRcode *qr=QRcode_encodeString("my string", 1, QR_ECLEVEL_L, QR_MODE_8,0);
```

**NOTE:** After experimenting with the parameters I have passed to this function, I have learned that one needs to be careful. Some combinations of parameters failed for no good reason. For example passing 0 as version or using QR_MODE_AN failed with "Invalid parameters". This might be bugs in the ancient version of the library that I am using You have been warned.

**Step 4: render image**

Finally, before cleaning up, you need to convert the output to bitmap so that it can be rendered on the screen. This is simpler than it sounds. Instead of listing a bunch of assumptions I will instead included my complete working minimalistic QRWidget implementation here. The interesting bits are in the overridden paintEvent() method.

**QRWidget.hpp**

```
#ifndef QRWIDGET_HPP
#define QRWIDGET_HPP

#include <QWidget>

class QRWidget : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QString data;
public:
    explicit QRWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setQRData(QString data);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

#endif // QRWIDGET_HPP
```

**QRWidget.cpp**

```
#include "QRWidget.hpp"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>    
#include <qrencode.h>

QRWidget::QRWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    data("Hello QR")//Note: The encoding fails with empty string so I just default to something else. Use the setQRData() call to change this.
{
}

void QRWidget::setQRData(QString data){
    this->data=data;
    update();
}

void QRWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe){
    QPainter painter(this);
    //NOTE: I have hardcoded some parameters here that would make more sense as variables.
    QRcode *qr = QRcode_encodeString(data.toStdString().c_str(), 1, QR_ECLEVEL_L, QR_MODE_8, 0);
    if(0!=qr){
        QColor fg("black");
        QColor bg("white");
        painter.setBrush(bg);
        painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
        painter.drawRect(0,0,width(),height());
        painter.setBrush(fg);
        const int s=qr->width>0?qr->width:1;
        const double w=width();
        const double h=height();
        const double aspect=w/h;
        const double scale=((aspect>1.0)?h:w)/s;
        for(int y=0;y<s;y++){
            const int yy=y*s;
            for(int x=0;x<s;x++){
                const int xx=yy+x;
                const unsigned char b=qr->data[xx];
                if(b &0x01){
                    const double rx1=x*scale, ry1=y*scale;
                    QRectF r(rx1, ry1, scale, scale);
                    painter.drawRects(&r,1);
                }
            }
        }
        QRcode_free(qr);
    }
    else{
        QColor error("red");
        painter.setBrush(error);
        painter.drawRect(0,0,width(),height());
        qDebug()<<"QR FAIL: "<< strerror(errno);
    }
    qr=0;
}
```

**Summary**
In this little post I have summarized my experience with getting a QR code generator working with Qt.

Comment: it is better to implement function `paintQrCode(QPainter &painter, const QRect &area, const QByteArray &data)`. Then this one function could be used to paint on `QWidget` or `QImage` or `QGraphicsWidget` avoiding duplication of code.

Comment: You are correct. I thought about doing it this way, but I felt like simplifying my answer as much as possible (it was a bit large). I might update it later!

Comment: You likely want     `QRcode *qr = QRcode_encodeString(data.toStdString().c_str(), 1, QR_ECLEVEL_L, QR_MODE_8, 0);`
 to be     `QRcode *qr = QRcode_encodeString(data.toStdString().c_str(), 1, QR_ECLEVEL_L, QR_MODE_8, 1);` to have case-insensitive QR Barcodes

Comment: Be careful: that library is LGPL, which is too restrictive for a lot of uses, such as use in an iOS app.

Answer (score 4):

The following is Qt code I used to update a label (qrCode) on a form with the QR code for "text".  The label is set to a fixed size (min and max width and height=256 in my case), and scaledContents true.  You might do something more efficient than the RGB32 format, but it really shouldn't matter for occasional updates.

```
void MyClass::updateQrCode( QString text )
{ using namespace qrcodegen;
  // Create the QR Code object
  QrCode qr = QrCode::encodeText( text.toUtf8().data(), QrCode::Ecc::MEDIUM );
  qint32 sz = qr.getSize();
  QImage im(sz,sz, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    QRgb black = qRgb(  0,  0,  0);
    QRgb white = qRgb(255,255,255);
  for (int y = 0; y < sz; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < sz; x++)
      im.setPixel(x,y,qr.getModule(x, y) ? black : white );
  ui->qrCode->setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(im.scaled(256,256,Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation),Qt::MonoOnly) );
}
```

using the Nayuki library - just the QrCode.cpp and .hpp files from here: https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator/tree/master/cpp

incorporated in my project with this trivial .pri file (kept in the same folder as the QrCode files):

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH  += $$PWD

HEADERS += $$PWD/QrCode.hpp

SOURCES += $$PWD/QrCode.cpp
```