# Drawing QR code with Qt in native C/C++

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, render, qr-code

I am successfully drawing and displaying the `QrCode` on a `QLabel`, but it's not recognised when I scan it. Here is the code I used - I made a small class with a static function:

```
void QrCodeDrawer::paintQR(QPainter &painter, const QSize sz, const QString &data, QColor fg)
{
    char *str=data.toUtf8().data();
    // NOTE: At this point you will use the API to get the encoding and format you want, instead of my hardcoded stuff:
    QrCode qr = QrCode::encodeText(str, QrCode::Ecc::HIGH);
    const int s=qr.size>0?qr.size:1;
    const double w=sz.width();
    const double h=sz.height();
    const double aspect=w/h;
    const double size=((aspect>1.0)?h:w);
    const double scale=size/(s+2);
    // NOTE: For performance reasons my implementation only draws the foreground parts in supplied color.
    // It expects background to be prepared already (in white or whatever is preferred).
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(fg);
    for(int y=0; y<s; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<s; x++) {
            const int color=qr.getModule(x, y);  // 0 for white, 1 for black
            if(0x0!=color) {
                const double rx1=(x+1)*scale, ry1=(y+1)*scale;
                QRectF r(rx1, ry1, scale, scale);
                painter.drawRects(&r,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And called it here:

```
QPixmap map(400,400);
QPainter painter(&map);
QrCodeDrawer::paintQR(painter,QSize(400,400),"Hello World", QColor("white"));
ui.qrCode->setPixmap(map);
```

I gave "Hello World" as input string and here is the code I get:
[image]

I got the source code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400254/how-to-draw-a-qr-code-with-qt-in-native-c-c).

Comment: It looks like it's inverted

Comment: Yup! It is getting recognised after I inverted the colors

Comment: I recognized it just fine on a random code-scanning ios app. But yes it's inverted.

Comment: @kim366 oh doh! you are right!, i also tried inverting and it worked!, i was at first wondering why the 3 squares at the edges were white inside(that's unusual) but it nerver came to my mind that it was inverted!

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall did you get it  to work without reverting it again ?

Comment: Yes it worked for me as it is, probably the apps developer accounted for the case. In fact the code can be of any colors, not just black and white.

Comment: but i thought that only the difference of colors matters, and not which is foreground or background...

Comment: I didn't, but @SingerOfTheFall did

Comment: After I finally found a solution, I just saw the comment of the author of the code snippet talking about setting a background color first.... so sorrry...

Comment: The QR Code specification does allow symbols with inverted colors. However, popular programs such as Barcode Scanner for Android do not recognize inversion unless you toggle an option, which is a hassle to do. Thus, don't draw inverted codes if you want the best compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same sample but had problems with garbage QR codes until I realised `str` can be a dangling pointer. I changed my code to this and it worked fine:

```
void QrCodeDrawer::paintQR(QPainter &painter, const QSize sz, const QString &data, QColor fg)
{
    // NOTE: At this point you will use the API to get the encoding and format you want, instead of my hardcoded stuff:
    QrCode qr = QrCode::encodeText(data.toUtf8().constData(), QrCode::Ecc::HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, by drawing the background first(white or any) and then draw the qr code on top of it with a different enough color...

```
void paintQR(QPainter &painter, const QSize sz, const QString &data, QColor fg, QColor bg)
{
    char *str=data.toUtf8().data();
    // NOTE: At this point you will use the API to get the encoding and format you want, instead of my hardcoded stuff:
    QrCode qr = QrCode::encodeText(str, QrCode::Ecc::HIGH);
    const int s=qr.size>0?qr.size:1;
    const double w=sz.width();
    const double h=sz.height();
    const double aspect=w/h;
    const double size=((aspect>1.0)?h:w);
    const double scale=size/(s+2);

    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    // Setting the background color....
    painter.setBrush(bg);
    for(int y=0; y<400; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<400; x++) {
            const double rx1=(x+1)*scale, ry1=(y+1)*scale;
            QRectF r(x, y, 1, 1);
            painter.drawRects(&r,1);
        }
    }
    //Drawing the Code....
    painter.setBrush(fg);
    for(int y=0; y<s; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<s; x++) {
            const int color = qr.getModule(x, y);  // 0 for white, 1 for black
            if(0x0!=color) {
                const double rx1=(x+1)*scale, ry1=(y+1)*scale;
                QRectF r(rx1, ry1, scale, scale);
                painter.drawRects(&r,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, if it is possible to ask for all of the code to make it work?

I am starting from complete nothing with my son, and he wants to make a QRcode generator, I thought if we could get one working we can study from there.

Best,
Mike

Comment: You should normally write this as a comment, or ask a new question, but not as an answer, since it doesnt answer the question.  That being said, i did this so loong ago, i dont even recall in which project and for what reasons i needed this. Needless to say i have no clue where the code is. but note that this was done in C++ with Qt, is it what you are using ? if not, if you just want to make qr codes, there are plenty of web based easy options..